# Refresh Controller doesn't appears after setting backgroundView in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

i don't understand why it is so, but when backgroundview is not setted, then refreshcontroller works perfect. When for example there isn't any data i set collectionview backgroundview something like called emptyBackgroudnview. it works in tableview great. but in collectionview it doesn't works. i tried to add `zPosition` using `self.refreshControl.layer.zPosition = (self.collectionView.backgroundView?.layer.zPosition)! + 1;` but it doesn't helps. I can't swipe down if backgroundview is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. Problem has bin fixed just added `collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`